# ¿Como integrar Firebase Cloud Messaging a una plataforma existente sin integrar Firebase Authentication?

Tags: firebase, firebase-auth, firebase-messaging

Actualmente existe un proyecto E-commerce con una base de datos gigante de usuarios. Según entiendo FCM puede enviar notificaciones push a dispositivos, crear segmentos, etc. Si no puedo integrar Firebase Authentication porque ya existe una autenticación en la tienda, ¿como le indico a Firebase que usuarios o dispositivos existen para enviar tales notificaciones?.

En este caso Firebase es una buena opción para enviar notificaciones?, ¿hay una mejor forma?.

Si sirve de algo, el proyecto está realizado con Node.js, Express y MongoDB.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: FCM usa los tokens asignados a los dispositivos para enviar los mensajes. De hecho, FCM no está para nada ligado al sistema de autentificación de Firebase ([fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58346698/5587982)). Para más detalles, [revisa la documentación](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/send-multiple?hl=es) y los ejemplos de código en la misma.

Comment: @A.Cedano tienes razón, no están ligados según la documentación. Aunque eso implicaría entonces que debo almacenar ese token de dispositivo en nuestra base de datos, correcto?

Comment: Claro, lo debes almacenar en la BD o en Firebase o donde sea.

Comment: El token es el medio de que se dispone para identificar cada dispositivo.  En la documentación de Firebase se hace referencia a estrategias de control para evitar guardar / enviar mensajes a tokens expirados o cosas por el estilo.

Comment: [Aquí más detalles sobre la administración de tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/manage-tokens?hl=es).

Comment: Revisaré toda esa documentación.